# Mapping particular type to Func<T>

Tags: c#-4.0, generics

What would be the best approach to map particular type to a Func of TResult? For example:

```
ViewModelBase GetScreen(Type type)
{
    // mapping code here
}

ScreenA GetScreenA()
{
   // returns new instance of ScreenA
}

// usage
var screen = GetScreen(typeof(ScreenA));
```

What I need to do here is to map ScreenA type to GetScreenA() method (strongly typed). Each screen inherits from ViewModelBase. What would be the best way to achieve this? I am not considering bunch of ifs as solution.

```
if (type = typeof(ScreenA))
    return GetScreenA();
else if ....
```

Comment: `Dictionary<Type, Func<ViewModelBase>>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a a dictionary to map to the different actions instead of using if statements.

```
private Dictionary<Type , Func<ViewModelBase>> Method2ObjectMap 
= new Dictionary<Type , Func<ViewModelBase>>
{ 
{ ScreenA, GetScreenA },
{ ScreenB, GetScreenB },
{ ScreenC, GetScreenC } 
};
```

And then call it with something like:

```
if(Method2ObjectMap.ContainsKey(ScreenB))
{
    return Method2ObjectMap[ScreenB];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will help you

```
class TypeA
{
}

class TypeB:TypeA
{
}

class TypeC : TypeA
{
}

private static Dictionary<Type, Func<TypeA>> ScreenMap = 
     new Dictionary<Type, Func<TypeA>>
{           
        {typeof(TypeA),()=> new TypeA() },
        {typeof(TypeB) ,()=> new TypeB()  },
        {typeof(TypeC),()=> new TypeC() }

};
```

And to use it

```
 TypeA a= ScreenMap[typeof(TypeA)]();
```